# What's wrong with my Fire Base code (React Native)

Tags: javascript, firebase, react-native, firebase-realtime-database

Trying to set up some testdata in React Native using Firebase. I have successfully installed using `$yarn add firebase`. I have added test data in FB like this: 
[FB data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JxtjJ.png)
And in my project I added the following code:

```
import * as firebase from 'firebase' 

const firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "AIzaSyBNKM6Ptbynkg5dEJkwMHNsZhUCsW2JqGE",
    authDomain: "testproject-f4c9f.firebaseapp.com",
    databaseURL: "https://testproject-f4c9f.firebaseio.com",
    projectId: "testproject-f4c9f",
    storageBucket: "testproject-f4c9f.appspot.com",
    messagingSenderId: "48530616964"
}
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)
```

Then in the rendering:

```
let mytext = ""

let testing = 
firebase.database().ref('testCategory/test1/FirstHeader');

testing.on('value', function(snapshot) {
    mytext = snapshot.val()
});

return(
    <View>
       <Text>{mytext}</Text>
    </View>
);
```

Running the app, nothing shows. Any ideas would be appreciated.

UPDATE: 
I managed to get it right in the `console.log` with this code:

```
let child = ""

var ref = firebase.database().ref("testCategory");

ref.once("value")
.then(function(snapshot) {
child = snapshot.child("test1/testHeader").val() 
console.log({child})
});
```

But for some reason I can't print it in the text output:

```
return(
    <View>
       <Text>{this.child}</Text>
    </View>
);
```

It's just blank...

Comment: try to put log of snapshot, check whether you are getting any data there or not?

Comment: No, it's empty :/

Comment: Got it to work for console now, but not text view: see update.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the data from the callback to the view. You should use a state manager like Redux or MobX, but for this example, you can just use the component state.

This is what your component should look like.

```
class Hello extends Component {
  state = {
    child: ''
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    firebase
      .database()
      .ref('testCategory')
      .on('value')
      .then(snapshot => {
        const child = snapshot.child('test1/testHeader').val()

        this.setState({
          child
        })
      })
  }

  render() {
    const { child } = this.state

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{child}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Tada!

Comment: Thanks, but I get an error saying `"Cannot read property 'child' of null"` which makes no sense since the log output shows a string.

Comment: You need to set `state` in your component. I'll update my answer with the full code.

Comment: Big thanks for the help, much appreciated! It worked save for one detail: I had to bind it, otherwise I got an error on this.setState. Add `this.setState( {    
          child
          })
        }.bind(this)); //BINDING TO SET STATE
    }` to your edit and I'll gladly accept the answer as having solved the issue. :)

Comment: That’s why I put `setState` in a closure, so `this` retains the correct scope.